# Lost in the Midst vs Mists of Time

Tags: meaning, popular-refrains, cliche

Which of the following is more correct, and why? My attempts at Googling haven't produced a definitive answer, and all seem as sensible as each other going from base definitions.

- Lost in the *mists* of time
- Lost in the *midst* of time (or, possibly, *midsts*)

Comment: Does your dictionary have an entry for *midsts*? If not, I would think that is your answer.

Comment: The plural of *midst* would indicate several places are in the middle of something (or perhaps some *things*), but the usage doesn't really belong in this context.

Comment: Related: Lost in the sands of time vs Lost in these hands of time. :^)

Comment: it's an eggcorn: see [midst](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=16232), and for the other mistaken direction [mist](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/english/217/mist/)

Comment: This is General Reference. Google Books claims 257,000 instances of *"mists of time"*, but only 14 for *"**midsts** of time"*. I'm surprised there were even that many.

Comment: Ah, that's my bad; should have been "midst" rather than "midsts".

Comment: I'm curious why this has been downvoted. Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Lost in the *mists* of time" is the typical phrase. The other is not and may come from people mishearing the phrase or people wanting an alternative construction (with a different meaning). If you do insist on using the latter, then it makes more sense to say, "lost in the midst of time" or "lost amongst moments of time".

I would read the two differently in the first place, though. The "*mists* of time" indicates something long ago, "lost in the fog" as it were. Being "lost in the *midst* of time" would indicate you're lost *in the middle* of time, which doesn't have any clear meaning to me unless you're a time-traveler. NewAlexandria's answer points out one potential reading (many online do, in fact, turn out to involve time travel or weird, mystical experiences that deviate from the typical phrase and its meaning).

The phrase "midst of time" does return plenty of results in Google (~80 000) but not nearly as many as "mist of time" or "mists of time" (~4 000 000). People may certainly extract meaning from using *midst*, as long as they're using it for the right purpose. They do not express the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The colloquialism "midst of time" means 'in the moment' - as in to be lost in the moment.

The "mists of time" is an expression involving an epic scale of time - very opposite to the midst(s) of a moment.

Answer (score -2):

My understanding is that the term is "Lost in the midst of time" (singular) but that this has been corrupted (possibly intentionally as a pun?)

Comment: The other way round, I think.

Comment: YMMV but I'll stick with my version, unless someone can prove the taxonomy.  But I certainly remember my English Master (many years ago) bemoaning the corruption of midst to mists

Comment: @Andrew Perhaps I should have included this in my answer, but I did various searches in the [BYU Corpora](http://corpus.byu.edu/coha/) (link is for American English 1810-2009, though I looked at the modern usage and in British English, too). I don't recall one result for "*midsts* of time". "*Midst* of time" occurs rarely and only to mean *the middle* of time (as opposed to the beginning or end, or to contrast against that which is *timeless*). "*Mists* of time" is common with meanings akin to "sands of time".

Comment: @Andrew And one of the earliest examples I found was [in 1848](http://corpus.byu.edu/coha/x4.asp?t=7193&ID=66902152): "...have suffered their ritual to decay, their ceremonies to degenerate.... Yes, the tradition which commanded them to meet, may have been **lost in the mists of time**, and the clamors of battle, and the changes of circumstances." From the beginning, the usage is poetical and not a corruption or mistake.

Comment: Perhaps the analogy with "sands of time" is relevant... this indicates the passing of time in an hourglass.

The midst of time indicates not at the beginning, and not in the present - but somewhere in the part in-between.

There are no "mists" in time...

Comment: Furthermore, other dictionary meanings of midst include enveloped by, in the thick of, surrounded (etc).